# Ajax requests not working on particular Android SDK

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a Phonegap/Jquery mobile app that i am trying to wrap for Android, but the target SDK I am using is not allowing Ajax/Cross-domain requests.
In short, the requests work fine with Android 4.0.3 (API 15), the most current, but not for Android 2.3.3 ( API 10), which is what i need to be compatible for a Galaxy Tablet.
I am having a hard time debugging this as I can't see the actual error since I am wrapped in phonegap and cant user Firebug/Chrome web tools. and I haven't had any luck over at developer.android.com.
I have tried the steps located at http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html, including
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.support.cors = true.

This didn't work either.
Can anyone help me out, I don't know what else to try.
Thanks!

Here is the a quick example of code. note that it returns success = true but hits the  'Response is not an XML element' error:

```
 return $.soapRequest({
        url: url,
        namespace: 'testns',
        returnJson: false,
        shortMethod: 'methodname',
        method: 'longmethodname',
        params: params || {},
        success: function(data) {
          if (data && data.documentElement) {
            // hits this on Android SDK 15
            if (successFn) {
              return successFn(data.documentElement);
            }
          }
          else {
            // hits this on Android SDK 10
            return fail("Response is not an XML element!");
          }
        },
        error: function(str) {
          return fail(str);
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://aurir.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/tutorial-getting-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler-http-proxy-tool/

Also, this might help as well http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

try to write  httpConnection with phonegap pluggin. it cound CrossDomain

httpPlugin.java

```
package com.android.test;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Log;

import com.android.connection.HTTPConnect;

public class HttpPlugin extends Plugin {
    public final String ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE = "SendCommand";
    private HTTPConnect httpConnect;

    public HttpPlugin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        httpConnect = new HTTPConnect();
    }

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE)) {
            try {
                String message = arg1.getString(0);
                String receiveString  = httpConnect.setURL(message);
                if(receiveString == null){
                    //show error result
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR,"kakaka");
                }else{
                    Log.v("MAN", "data received");
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
                }
                result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

plugin.xml file

Httpplugin .js

```
var Httpplugin = function () {};

Httpplugin.prototype.post = function (message, successCallback, failureCallback) {  
//  navigator.notification.alert("OMG");
    return cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'Httpplugin', 'SendCommand', [message]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("http", new Httpplugin());
});
```